# How to change the status of a scenario in behave python

Tags: python, python-behave

```
def after_scenario(context, scenario):
if scenario.status == Status.failed and context.status == "negative":
    scenario.status = Status.passed
if scenario.status == Status.passed and context.status == "negative":
    scenario.status = Status.failed
```

I am getting HOOK-ERROR in after_scenario: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using scenario.set_status(Status.passed)